# Search topology not created and found Unable to retrieve topology

Tags: 2013, search, enterprise-search

In a newly configured test sharepoint 2013 farm

it has

2 app server

1 dedicated search server ( for all components except query component )

2 WFE servers. ( query processing component)

I created new search service application and it was work fine users was able to search but for doing Index reset

-i deleted content source for our sharepoint web application

-i did Index Reset and after i deleted search service application it self.

after doing these steps i tried to re create again new search service application  using central administration.

after creation of  search service application in search topology i found below message

Search Application Topology

Unable to retrieve topology component health states. This may be because the admin component is not up and running.

- when i check in failed job in monitoring i found below jobs failing

Search Custom Dictionaries Update
Query Classification Dictionary Update for Search Application Search Service Application PORTAL.

and  in WFE servers event viewer i found below error messages

Log Name:      Application

Source:        Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Foundation

Date:          9/16/2015 10:45:32 AM

Event ID:      8313

Task Category: Topology

Level:         Error

Keywords:

User:          NT AUTHORITY\IUSR

Computer:      XXXPortalWFE02.xxxportal.com

Description:

A failure was reported when trying to invoke a service application: EndpointFailure

Process Name: w3wp

Process ID: 7624

AppDomain Name: /LM/W3SVC/716261631/ROOT-1-130868338417901285

AppDomain ID: 2

Service Application Uri: urn:schemas-microsoft-

y=https://xxxportalapp01:32844/Topology/topology.svc

Active Endpoints: 4

Failed Endpoints:2

Affected Endpoint: http://xxxportalapp01:32843/xxxxxxx5/SearchService.svc

Event Xml:

```
<Provider Name="Microsoft-SharePoint Products-SharePoint Foundation" Guid="{xxxxx}" />

<EventID>8313</EventID>

<Version>15</Version>

<Level>2</Level>

<Task>13</Task>

<Opcode>0</Opcode>

<Keywords>0x4000000000000000</Keywords>

<TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-09-16T07:45:32.320361600Z" />

<EventRecordID>61704</EventRecordID>

<Correlation ActivityID="{A7742E9D-8666-A08A-32A3-70B6BB3D51A8}" />

<Execution ProcessID="7624" ThreadID="15540" />

<Channel>Application</Channel>

<Computer>XXXPortalWFE02.xxxportal.com</Computer>

<Security UserID="S-1-5-17" />
```

```
<Data Name="string0">EndpointFailure</Data>

<Data Name="string1">w3wp</Data>

<Data Name="int2">7624</Data>

<Data Name="string3">/LM/W3SVC/716261631/ROOT-1-130868338417901285</Data>

<Data Name="int4">2</Data>

<Data Name="string5">urn:schemas-microsoft-
```

963&authority=https://xxxportalapp01:32844/Topology/topology.svc

```
<Data Name="int6">4</Data>

<Data Name="int7">2</Data>

<Data Name="string8">http://xxxportalapp01:32843/5c199d5d5/SearchService.svc</Data>
```